# Find all $\alpha>0$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^k}{k!^{\alpha}}$ exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

This week's rainy Sunday afternoon problem:

The function $f(x,\alpha)$ for $\alpha$ real and positive, is defined as:

$$ f(x,\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^k}{k!^{\alpha}}$$

Find all $\alpha$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,\alpha)$ exists.

Comment: For $\;\alpha =1\;$ that series is $\;e^{-x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0\;$ , so the limit exists *at least* for $\;\alpha\ge1\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha>0$, by the Stirling-formula, we have:
$$f(x,\alpha)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\dfrac{x^k}{k!^\alpha}\approx C\cdot\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\dfrac{x^k}{(\frac{k^\alpha}{e^\alpha})^k}=C\cdot\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k(\dfrac{e^\alpha\cdot x}{k^{\alpha}})^k.$$
Thus by Leibniz criteria, for $x>0$, we have conditionally convergence. For $x=0$, $f(0,\alpha)=0$, and for $x<0$, let $y:=(-x)^{1/\alpha}$. For a fixed $x$, there is a positive integer $M$, such that for every $k>M$:
$$(\frac{e\cdot y}{k})^\alpha<\frac{1}{2}.$$
Thus we have:
$$C\cdot\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(\dfrac{e^\alpha\cdot x}{k^{\alpha}})^k<constant+C\cdot\sum\limits_{k=M+1}^{\infty}(\dfrac{1}{2})^k<\infty.$$

Comment: $M$ depends on $y$ so it seems to me that the constant isn't all that constant. Then if a bound can still be found, the limit may still not exist.

Comment: You're right, but it's the $x<0$ case. The limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x,\alpha)$ still exists.